# windows batch file not exiting

Tags: batch-file, task, taskmanager

I am not good at windows scripting. (I am linux guy)
I have to delete files which they are older than n days in two directories. 
I am using 2 forfiles command in script. When I run the script manually there is no problem so it's running and finishing its job properly and it takes about 30 seconds to finish

So I created a task to run this batch file everyday in task scheduler
When Task Scheduler executes the script, the script could not end and I could see a running forfiles command in task manager and following day task manager creates a log the script/command is already running. So I am terminating script and run **"manually"** again, it successfully run and finishes its job in 30-35 seconds again

My script is like that

```
y:
cd \<path1>
forfiles /s /d -120 /m *.* /c "cmd /c del @path"
cd \<path2>
forfiles /s /d -120 /m *.* /c "cmd /c del @path"
EXIT
```

How can I run this batch file from task manager properly ?

Thanks

Comment: I assume, `Y:` is a network drive. Your scheduled task has no connected network drive. You'll  have to connect it with `net use y: \\server\folder` inside your batch file, maybe you have also to give valid credentials.

Comment: Hello

you are right so Y is network drive but there is no connectivity issue with drive. I could run the script manually without any problem 

Thanks

Comment: insert a `net use >>script.log` and / or a  `dir y:\<path1> >>script.log` into your batchfile and see it yourself.

Comment: Please change the title of your question to be more specific, the current one is very poor!

Comment: I have added /P  option with full path of directory and it's works

Answer (score 0):

To me it sounds like rights issue.  How do you execute your script (directly via start a program or via batch file)?  Which windows you are running?

On Windows 7 and Task Scheduler:

Have correct user filled out - who has the rights to run the task and access the files.

Try running your script with checkbox `Run with highest privileges` checked.

*Edit*

Stefan is right.  If you are running it from within batch file you have to map the network drive with correct credentials:

`net use <driver letter> "\\<servername>\<sharename>" /user:<username> <password>`

You could do it the following way:

```
IF NOT EXIST y:\ (
  ECHO "The y: drive does not exist.  Mapping"
  net use y: "\\<servername>\<sharename>" /user:<username> 
)
```

Comment: Hello Tukan 

sorry for missing input

OS is Windows 2012 R2 
I am not OS and/or Domain Admin  so I am running this script with normal user rights

I have applied highest privileges checkbox and tried again but no progress, script/forfiles commmand is running last 4 minutes (there is no file to delete :) )

Thanks for your reply

Comment: @user984074 I don't have a Win2012R2 to test it on.  But what Stephan says is likely.